# no such file to load -- rack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rack

Sometimes, my rails application gives an error (no such file to load -- rack) even if rack is installed.

[Gemfile]
gem 'rack', '1.2.1'

If I refresh the page, it loads fine.
So it's not the gem problem.
What could cause the error?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think if you start your website locally, this will not happen. So what service did you use? I've encountered this kind of bugs on DreamHost.

For DreamHost, the problem is they use different version (older) of Rack, which is not compatible with newest version of Rails. Try to specify the Rack version in your Gemfile (and in most cases, you have to downgrade Rails as well). It may help.

Another possible reason is that you use RVM on your local machine, but for servers, for example, Passenger + Nginx/Apache, RVM may not work well (actually, I'm always getting errors using Passenger + RVM). Specifying your Gem directory may help.

Comment: You're very correct. I use DreamHost VPS. My dev environment is RVM. Another weird thing is that even if I do 'bundle install' my rails app gives me that "no such file to load — rack". I have to do 'gem install rack -v 1.2.1' manually. It might be related to my 'bundle install --deployment'. I am not sure, though.

Comment: I'm not using Dreamhost VPS, but DreamHost shared server. I think that VPS will be much more better than shared server. For shared server, what I did is ading these lines to config.ru: ENV['GEM_HOME']="#{ENV['HOME']}/.gems"
ENV['GEM_PATH']="#{ENV['GEM_HOME']}:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8"
require 'rubygems'
Gem.clear_paths
You can have a try. It specifies the Gem path.