# Setting folder with Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash

I saw [no such file to load -- rack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830000/no-such-file-to-load-rack).

But that did not answer my question.

I am getting this when:

```
./script/server
```

This is some information about my env:

1. Using RVM 1.21.15 with ruby 1.8.7-p72
2. `bundle exec gem list | grep rack` gives me `rack (1.1.2)`
3. `cat Gemfile | grep rack` returns empty.
4. `cat Gemfile | grep rails` returns `gem 'rails', '2.3.14'`.
5. `cat Gemfile.lock | grep rack` returns

   ```
     rack (~> 1.1.0)
   rack (1.1.2)
   ```

## Update

1. `bundle config path` returns `".bundle/gems"`
2. and `p $:.grep /rack/` returns `.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.2/lib` which does not exist, even after running `bundle install`.
3. but `.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.2/` does exist. Note the ruby version.

`rvm current` `ruby-1.8.7-p72`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did:

```
# remove ./bundle/gems dir
git clean -fd
# bundle again
bundle
```

Now it works.